# when alert button numbers are more than 6,how to display them one(row) by one correctly?

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

There i have a problem. When i add button to my alert, but if the button numbers are more than 6, the button will show beyond the alert view frame. How can i display them correctly just like a scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about splitting it up into two UIAlertViews? Try making your 5th/6th button a "More Options" button, and handle that within the dismissedWithButton function. Then have the last button be a "Cancel" button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It is maybe a solution.But if i have lots of button, how many alerts should i create.What i want is that the buttons can show in one alert, and them can be scrolled? But i can not find this method?

Comment: Mm.. well, you could possibly subclass the UIAlertView and create a scrollable interface with all the buttons your heart desires.. However, I do not think it is worth the work (and I think that would be a lot of work). If you are going to have a lot of options, you are probably best off just creating a UITableView controller & xib. Pass an array of options to it, push it onto the navigationcontroller, and get the option the user selects using didSelectRow. Here is a good link to help you get started: http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/